# show the installation PWA Prompt without user iteraction

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I tried to show the user the PWA Prompt installation message after the website page loaded.
I know that it works using a button, but we want to improve our installation conversion by showing the installation prompt after the site is loaded.

for example, with this code, I get an error of "The prompt() method must be called with a user gesture":

```
//install from button
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
    // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
    e.preventDefault();
    // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
    this.deferredPrompt = e;

    console.log('beforeinstallprompt!');
    // if askedOnce is true, no need to ask again.
    this.showPwaPrompt = !this.askedOnce;
  });


function acceptPwaPrompt() {
  this.showPwaPrompt = false;
  this.askedOnce = true;
  this.deferredPrompt.prompt();  // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
  this.deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
    if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
      console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
    } else {
      console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
    }

    this.deferredPrompt = null;
  });
}

setTimeout(() => { acceptPwaPrompt();}, 2000)
```

Comment: `beforeinstallprompt` is non-standard - what browser are you testing this in?

Comment: I'm using, Chrome

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is impossible. A website must not be able to install itself just by being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [beforeInstallPromptEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent).

NOTE: This is experimental and can change in future releases. Works on all chromium browsers. But, doesn't work on firefox and safari.

I researched before and found only this. Works flawless in chrome/edge.

You can use it like that:
REACT EXAMPLE

---

After checking, if installation is allowed, which means you can prompt and user doesn't have it installed on phone/computer.

---

```
/**
 * The BeforeInstallPromptEvent is fired at the Window.onbeforeinstallprompt handler
 * before a user is prompted to "install" a web site to a home screen on mobile.
 *
 * This is an experimental technology. Be cautious when using it.
 *
 * @compatibility {@link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent#Browser_compatibility}
 * @see {@link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent}
 */
interface BeforeInstallPromptEvent extends Event {
  /**
   * Returns an array of DOMString items containing the platforms on which the event was dispatched.
   * This is provided for user agents that want to present a choice of versions to the user such as,
   * for example, "web" or "play" which would allow the user to chose between a web version or
   * an Android version.
   */
  readonly platforms?: Array<string>

  /**
   * Returns a Promise that resolves to a DOMString containing either "accepted" or "dismissed".
   */
  readonly userChoice?: Promise<{
    outcome: 'accepted' | 'dismissed'
    platform: string
  }>

  /**
   * Allows a developer to show the install prompt at a time of their own choosing.
   * This method returns a Promise.
   */
  prompt?(): Promise<void>
}

const [isInstallAllowed, setIsInstallAllowed] = useState<boolean | undefined>(undefined)

const [installEvent, setInstallEvent] = useState<BeforeInstallPromptEvent | null>(null)


const beforeAppInstallpromptHandler = (e: BeforeInstallPromptEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  setIsInstallAllowed(true)
  setInstallEvent(e)
}


window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', beforeAppInstallpromptHandler)
```